# Button to Image Button

Tags: html, image, button

I have a dropdown menu which you can choose your location, then you click on the go button, which will direct you to another page,

This is the buttons code in html:

```
<input type="button" name="button" class="gobutton" onclick="openDir(this.form);">
```

and this is the part in CSS

`.gobutton{background-color: url (../images/go.jpg);   width:150px; height:50px; padding:0;  border:0;}`

Problem I have is that it is not changing the button to the image, its BLANK.

Comment: `background-color`...?

Comment: You have `background-color` where you should have `background-image` or `background`.

Comment: Consider using a `<button/>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/wezesa/1/edit?html,css,output)**

- background-color is *not* `background-image`
- also remove the space between `url` and `(`

```
.gobutton{
    background: url(../images/go.jpg); /* or use background-image */
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this button code instead:

`<button name="button" class="gobutton" onclick="openDir(this.form);"><img src="../images/go.jpg"/></button>`

Or, you can do it the way you are already doing it with an `<input>` element.  The code should then be using `background-image` not `background-color`.

However, I would use the `<button>` tag over the `<input>` tag because you can insert direct HTML into it.  Just use whatever is easiest for you.

Comment: As a response to the previously deleted comment, what you said was true. it's just a preference thing.  I find it easier to use `<button>`.  Also, the button stretches to fit the image, unlike an `<input>` button.  You can use `-webkit-appearance: none;` to take away the button styles.  http://jsfiddle.net/w2rxo5og/